# Как сохранить xlsx файл в pdf?

Tags: python, excel, pdf

Всем привет! Вопрос такой: как через Excel сохранить в PDF формате? Или может другим способом как-то конвертировать? Вот код:

```
try:
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    Excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    Excel.Visible = 0
    wb1 = Excel.Workbooks.Open(u'D:\\test.xlsx')
    wb1.SaveAs(u'D:\\test', FileFormat = 6)
    wb1.Close()
except Exception as e:
    print (e)
finally:
    Excel.Quit()
```

В этом коде FileFormat = 6 - делает сохранение в CSV.
Но через файл формат нельзя сохранить в PDF.
Есть ссылка на документацию к возможным форматам:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/ex...
И к FixedFF:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/ex...
SaveAsFixedFormat не получается. Как правильно написать сохранение в PDF?
Спасибо!

Comment: В VBA так: `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=sPath & sNamePDF, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False` Путь сохранения и имя -  `sPath & sNamePDF`. Лишние опции можно не задавать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашёл!

```
wb1.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, 'D:\\test.pdf')
```